# How can I delete derived data in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I have installed Xcode 9 today morning. It works fine but I want to understand the way to delete the derived data.

Is there any specific way to remove it?

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Open Xcode -> click Preferences...

[image]

Now tap on `Location` tab then click on arrow same as below image

[image]

Comment: This screenshot is from Xcode 7 and while this information is correct, how does it differ from @TehasArdeshna's answer?

Comment: Now check my updated image @the4kman

Comment: tried. Not working.

Comment: @TamásSengel It doesn't really.  It looks as though by the time stamps that they were both working on the answer at the same time and people ended up liking this one more because it had more clarity to the response I would assume.

Answer (score 6):

Open Xcode -> click on Xcode menu on top bar -> preferences -> location tab. Here you can see the path of derived data. Click on the right arrow and delete all files from there. [image]