# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib Reason: image not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, dyld

I'm getting this error upon launch of my app.  I am building under Xcode 9.0 (9A235) on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.  I also tried building under Xcode 8.3.3 with the same result.  The project is generally Objective C, but the framework YouAppi.framework is Swift:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7D3E2815-4CA3-4258-AEF6-C0626055A8F2/dingbats.app/Frameworks/YouAppi.framework/YouAppi
  Reason: image not found
```

At first glance, this appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771796/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftavfoundation-dylib), but the error is different in that one.  In that other question, the Reason is **no suitable image found**, where mine is **image not found**.

I've tried the following to resolve:

1. Remove and re-add the framework
2. Clean and Option+Clean the project
3. Delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder
4. Build Settings -> Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries = Yes
5. Build Settings -> Strip Swift Symbols = No
6. Build Settings -> Linking -> Runpath Search Paths --

   - added @loader_path
   - added @rpath
   - added @executable_path/Frameworks
7. Checked developer and distribution certificates that Trust was set to Use System Defaults
8. Checked that I have latest WWDR and G2 certificates installed
9. Checked validity of above-mentioned certificates
10. Moved YouAppi.framework into Frameworks/ folder.  (It was originally in a "Third-Party Frameworks" folder.)
11. Tried copying libswiftAVFoundation.dylib into my project's Frameworks folder

I haven't moved to a new computer recently.

I have the same result on my iPhone 7+ running iOS 11.0.23 (15A432) as well as an iPad Mini 1 running iOS 9.3.5 (13G36).

Also tried this:

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Ideas?

Comment: Does it run on another computer?

Comment: @Linus, I don't have another computer to build it from, but for running I've tried the two devices mentioned (iPhone 7+ and iPad Mini), with same result.

Comment: Want to share the project? I could test it for you using my machine.

Comment: would if I could

Comment: This solved it for me - many thanks! "Build Settings -> Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries = Yes"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When including a framework built with Swift in a non-Swift project, the Swift standard libraries need to be copied into the final output.  Xcode has a checkbox for this (*#4 in the original question*), but apparently there's a bug where, in some cases, it *doesn't* actually happen.

I saw another thread somewhere that said this happens when you have a framework built with Swift, which is built for multiple architectures, such as armv7 and arm64.  (See the thread [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52139).)

In any case, the solution is to add them all manually.  The files you are looking for are in **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos**.

What I did was this:

Step 1. Open **Terminal** and type this, copying the libraries to a new folder, **swiftStdLib**, in your home directory.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
mkdir ~/swiftStdLib
cp libswift*.dylib ~/swiftStdLib
```

Step 2. Within Xcode, go to **General** -> **Embedded Binaries**, and hit the **+** to add.  Click **Add Other**, then navigate to your home folder/**swiftStdLib**.  Select all and hit enter.

Step 3. Clean and build the project.

Hope this helps someone.

**UPDATE FOR XCODE 11:**

In Xcode 11.3, the Swift libraries folder has changed to include the major Swift version number.  The original question was based on Xcode 9, so this probably changed earlier than Xcode 11.3, but I haven't checked.

The new folder is **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphoneos**.

So that makes Step 1, above, this instead:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphoneos
mkdir ~/swiftStdLib
cp libswift*.dylib ~/swiftStdLib
```

Comment: This helped.. All bullshit of deleting here and there was not a solution!

Comment: Btw,, i got error of Symbol not found:.. what to do with that.. did you know about it?

Comment: SYMBOL not found? - might be a different issue.  Maybe start a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @drewster, I had found out the problem. It was actually Swift Compiler issue which not related to this. So it was solved..

Comment: @drewster and Kasnady could you please help me to navigate to your home folder/swiftStdLib ? I really really need your help. I can't find folder/swiftStdLib :( . here is the pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoUri.png

Comment: @Alexa289 in your screenshot it would be /Users/yourname/swiftStdLib - that is AFTER you run the commands above.

Comment: I try do that now i catch: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty

Comment: Excellent, saved my day! Thanks :)

Comment: @Kasnady hello, I am getting the same error msg like you 'Symbol not found'. How did you solve that problem please? (in Xcode 9.2, iOS 12 iPhone 6s.)

Comment: when I run cp command I get,,, zsh: no matches found: libswift*.dylib ,, any idea??

Comment: @AmolGangadhare The Swift libraries folder has been renamed to include the Swift version number.  So for example, in Xcode 11.3, instead of one of the subfolders in the path being named 'swift', it's now named 'swift-5.0'.  Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: I am getting error against every library that I added like this -- "Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded library '***.dylib' was built for iOS.". Please that I am using Xcode 11.3

Answer (score 4):

**Before adding frameworks try this:**

I deleted derived data in xcode9 -  it works for me

refer link below: How to delete contents from derived data

[How can I delete derived data in Xcode 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468220/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-9)

Comment: Deleting the app from the phone, then deleting derived data and trying to build to device again resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting old developer certificates from Keychain Access helped for me.

Comment: how do we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Just cleaning the project sometimes seems to work for me. I have noticed this happen more frequently when I have a swfit/objc/c++ project combination.

Answer (score -1):

> Simple step to follow

**Project -> Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks -> +.**

It will works for all.. Perfect solution for everyone.

- Add library in Link Binary with Libraries &
- Add new Copy Files Phrase, Select framework in destination section and import library there.
- And Run your code.. Magic.. Enjoy

NOTE:-Please make sure "Copy only when installing" in Copy files is unchecked

[image]