# App runs perfectly on simulators but not on physical devices [on iOS 13.3.1]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, iosdeployment

**The app runs perfectly on every simulator but when I try to run it on a physical device** , it shows the following error :-

[image]

I also tried to run it on various physical devices like iPhone 6 , iPhone 7 and iPhone 11.
After that **I came to a conclusion that the error is occurring on devices running on version of iOS 13.3.1 as App only runs successfully on iPhone 6 which is running on iOS 12.4.4**

I also tried to run new project on same physical devices but it keeps showing me blank screen (on devices running on iOS 13.3.1) and if I install any framework in that new project then it's showing same error as shown in image.

I already tried:

- cleaning project
- restarting project
- restarting  Mac
- reinstalling Xcode

Comment: Are you added framework in project under `Build Phases` -> `Embed Frameworks`? and error can also occur  if you are using framework in different version then one currently being used.

Comment: can you elaborate more as I'm new in iOS development

Comment: and if it is error of framework then why the new project can't run (it has no framework )

Comment: Try to quit xcode, clean and build project again

Comment: already tried cleaning project , restart project , restart  Mac, reinstall Xcode

Comment: When you are build new project it also gives same error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207014/discussion-between-kishan-bhatiya-and-shivam-parmar).

Comment: is it still gives error?

Comment: @ShivamParmar check this post : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8324476

Comment: @ AlbinMrngStar  according to reference you share its problem because of account but I don't think its relatable in my case because I try a new blank project with same account and it work ....

Comment: Can you retry after cleaning Derived Data?

Comment: yes I tried it several times ... :(

Comment: This might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759183/309046
If this didn't work share Podfile and Build Phase screenshot (Link Binary with Libraries and Embed Pods Framework).

Comment: thanks for suggestion but still I get same error ... :(

Comment: Are you using Cocoapods or spm?

Comment: I use CocoaPods ...

Comment: Have a look at this issue on [Alamofire Github](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051) which has been raised.

Comment: You say that the app just shows a blank screen when you run it on a device with iOS 13. What does it show when you run it on a iOS 12 device?

Comment: it run properly in ios12 device...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Alamofire issue tracker](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051) peoples are suggesting that doing these steps:

- remove/comment `use_frameworks!` in Podfile
- add `use_modular_headers!` in Podfile
- pod update
- pod install
- clean and run

solves the issue with using free Apple ID on iOS 13.3.X

Comment: This is working for every user of Alamofire framework so it must work for you unless you are using other frameworks like SQLite.swift.

Comment: after this implementation i got Could not build objective-c module error in all pods how can i solve this . ?

Comment: You issue is so generic there is no way we can help you. Post a new question with detailed explanation of your setup.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue, and most people say it is a problem with using a non-paid Apple ID. Some kind of provisioning thing.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051

Comment: so is there any solution to run without paid id ?

Answer (score 1):

> Apple blocked utilizing external frameworks on free accounts with 13.3.1 upgrade. Try downgrading to 13.3.

Reference and solution here: [Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises iOS 13.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096258/library-not-loaded-rpath-fblpromises-framework-fblpromises-ios-13-3-1)