# Xcode - App using AWS Frameworks runs on Simulator but crashes on device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11.3

I created an app in Xcode 10 Beta using some AWS frameworks on iOS. This ran fine. Recently when I revisited the project, updating to Xcode 11, the app displays a white screen on startup, with a signal SIGABRT on Thread 1.

I'm at wits end. I've tried variously embedding the frameworks (under 'General' in project settings), linking binary with libraries (under 'Build Phases'), copying files and copying in the frameworks, but none of these have worked. I've also tried cleaning and rebuilding, and deleting DerivedData, but these have not worked either.

Would appreciate any advice. Cheers.

```
Pods used:

PODS:
  - AWSAuthCore (2.9.1):
    - AWSCore (= 2.9.1)
  - AWSAuthUI (2.9.1):
    - AWSAuthCore (= 2.9.1)
    - AWSCore (= 2.9.1)
  - AWSCognito (2.9.1):
    - AWSCore (= 2.9.1)
  - AWSCognitoIdentityProvider (2.9.1):
    - AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF (= 1.0.1)
    - AWSCore (= 2.9.1)
  - AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF (1.0.1)
  - AWSCore (2.9.1)
  - AWSLambda (2.9.1):
    - AWSCore (= 2.9.1)
  - AWSMobileClient (2.9.1):
    - AWSAuthCore (= 2.9.1)
    - AWSCognitoIdentityProvider (= 2.9.1)
  - AWSS3 (2.9.1):
    - AWSCore (= 2.9.1)
  - AWSUserPoolsSignIn (2.9.1):
    - AWSAuthCore (= 2.9.1)
    - AWSCognitoIdentityProvider (= 2.9.1)
  - SwiftKeychainWrapper (3.2.0)
```

Screenshot of debug session:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full credit to Shebuka's answer at [App runs perfectly on simulators but not on physical devices [on iOS 13.3.1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014739/app-runs-perfectly-on-simulators-but-not-on-physical-devices-on-ios-13-3-1)

After restoring from the last working version of my project,

- I closed Xcode.
- I commented out `use_frameworks!` and added `use_modular_headers!` to the Podfile.
- I then ran `pod update` and `pod install` from the folder my project was located in.
- I reopened the project (the xcworkspace file) and cleaned and built the project.

And presto! It's working again.