# Not running in Device with Cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

My Xcode project is running fine in the simulator, but when I try to run it in the device its crashing and showing the following error in console.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/co....................
 Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/348225A0-
```

I tried with a sample project without cocoa pods, then it's running in iPhone but when installing cocoa pods then it's making the problem again.

my pod file

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reason: no suitable image found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found)

Comment: i tried all the answers from that link, nothing solved my issue

Comment: And this https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051#issuecomment-580139830?!

Comment: From last 3 days, i tried almost all the solutions from google search results, At last i posted in SO

Comment: Have you tried to delete and reinstall cocoapods?

Comment: yes i tried ...

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014739/app-runs-perfectly-on-simulators-but-not-on-physical-devices-on-ios-13-3-1

Comment: if your device os version is 13.1.3, just comment `use_framework` and run your pod install