# Problems in generating UIKit/UICloudSharingController.h

Tags: swift, xcode, icloud-api

When I compile my app I get a long list of errors all connected to

> UIKit/UICloudSharingController.h

as you may see in the attached screenshot.

What does it mean and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with Restarting Xcode, Clearing derived data?

Comment: I restarted Xcode and cleaned the build folder from Xcode; I was not able to find the Derived Data folder in Version 10.1 any longer. The compilation gives the same errors after that.

Comment: This may help:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468220/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-9

Comment: Ok, thanks, I found and deleted the Derived Data folder, but the error remained.

Comment: I even ported, for good measure, the iCloud management file to Swift, but that changed nothing as well.

Comment: Can you share any demo project with this error?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what part of the code produces the error in order to create a demo. I thought it was the CloudKit section in objective c and so I ported it to Swift, but that changed nothing. I have two other simpler apps that present no problems. Moreover the problem seems connected to the compiler, more than to my code, notwithstanding something in my code evidently produces it. It would be great if at least I could do something to know better.

Comment: lets connect on skype. My skype id is dharmesh.kheni.root

Comment: I am downloading it. When I am done I shall contact you. At any rate all error seem connected to lines: 
- (instancetype)initWithShare:(CKShare *)share container:(CKContainer *)container;
and
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong, nullable) CKShare *share;
in the generated UICloudSharingController class.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded it and invited you.

Comment: I am still waiting for some help, I tried reinstalling Xcode and even the system to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to a very weird problem Apple helped me to find out. In practice I used flag share in #if clauses to shield piece of code in the appropriate target. What I found was that this flag is also used somewhere by Apple itself and so I shielded even some parts of its code with the errors I reported. Once renamed to sharespare, the name of the app, the problem all but disappeared.