# react-native run-ios Build is freezing

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native

I have a project that is on two different MacBooks and using the same git repo. On one it works perfectly on the other it fails at `react-native run-ios`.

If I use --verbose, the build hangs at

> debug IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = "../../"

Xcode also takes a very long time to open the project and workspace

If I open Xcode, the build then continues but ultimately fails. I got the following problem report from Xcode.

```
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            Xcode
Version:               10.1 (14460.46)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [27658]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-08-16 15:28:17.531 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G87)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.6 (16P6568)
Anonymous UUID:        2D0367AA-A050-753B-B203-81F1EE1A1440

Sleep/Wake UUID:       FBD96B28-D088-4F34-A40E-F1007B0BD328

Time Awake Since Boot: 35000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       7000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        7  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7f9790ef78f0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [27658]
```

I have tried the following

Changed Xcode to legacy build
Deleted and reinstalled node_modules
Deleting Derived data
Downgraded Xcode
Cleared react cache

Comment: Try deleting the derived data and rebuilding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468220/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-9#targetText=2%20Answers&targetText=Open%20Xcode%20%2D%3E%20click%20on%20Xcode,delete%20all%20files%20from%20there.

Comment: I tried it but it hasn't helped

Comment: I have been able to get it to work on the machine by creating a new user

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by logging out of iCloud after that I was able to run the build seamlessly. logged back in and it still works.

Hope this helps someone